# How can I configure Visual Studio to focus on the Error List window instead of Output window after building?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio focuses the Output window after each build; even reopening it if I close it. I'd rather it open the Error List window instead.

How can I configure my VS to focus on the Error List window instead of Output window?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is very annoying, happened to me countless times before, here's how i deal with it:

```
under the window menu select 'Reset Window Layout'
after its done immediately close the output window in design mode
```

this bug only happens if you chose Visual Basic programming layout for the default layout at the time you were installing VS2010.

Comment: This worked at first but after restarting visual studio the problem returns.

Answer (score 44):

In `Tools->Options`, on the left select `Project and Solutions->General` and then uncheck `Show Output window when build starts` on the right.

Provided that output window is docked and it's not in Auto hide mode... i mean If you can view output window.

Now, if your cursor is focused on the code editor, after the build, the cursor maintains it focus on code editor, although even if the cursor is somewhere else, like the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too and neither of the previous solutions worked. In my case, Gallio was overriding the setting and showing test output every time in the output window. I disabled the add-in (Tools -> Add in manager) since I was using Icarus anyway and haven't been bothered since.